I am experiencing trouble with the formatting of my heading in overleaf
All of my other headings displayed correctly but for this specific heading, there is a wid gap between the words of my subsection and subsubsection. I have tried removing any newlines in the code, but had no luck, I also tried a pagebreak before the subsection, but had the same error.
The error message is the following:
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 120--120


Welcome to TeX.SE! Please do not show code in an image, we can not copy and test on our own computer! Please make a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}. And please note: A screenshot can never replace a MWE, even if is shows some code.

Do remember that center is an environment, so \begin{center} ... \end{center} not \center{...} (not running the end part can cause issues).

I can reproduce the issue:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\subsection}
 {\large\bfseries}
 {\thesubsection.}
 {0.5em}
 {}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\center{AAA}

\subsection*{Some title}

\end{document}


Where's the problem?

The \center command exists, but it should never be used in the document environment; it can be possibly be used for defining new environments and it must be accompanied by the corresponding \endcenter.

The \center command doesn't take an argument: it's a declaration that goes on forever (taking grouping into account).


You're issuing \center at the outer level, which means that its setting goes on until the end of the document.
Interaction with titlesec makes the two word subsection title to be spread.
If you want to center a few images, use
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[<options>]{filename}

\bigskip % of course, 2cm is too much

\includegraphics[<options>]{filename}
\end{center}

As many figures as you want can be accommodated with the same scheme.
By the way, consecutive \[...\] equations are wrong. I guess you load amsmath, so you have available
\begin{gather*}
<first formula> \\
<second formula> \\
<third formula>
\end{gather*}

